# Iterate through hours in a day

Tags: c#

having a DateTime variable, for example:

```
DateTime testDate = new DateTime(2011,12,15,00,00,00);
```

how can I implement a foreach loop for every hour of this day?

Something like:

```
foreach (int myHour in testDate.Date)
{

}
```

but in this way does not compile.

Answer (score 16):

It is not a good idea to loop 24, because this will not work on days with 25 or 23 hours (time change, daylight saving...).

Use the `AddHour` function and a target date.

```
DateTime testDate = new DateTime(2011, 12, 15, 00, 00, 00, DateTimeKind.Local);
DateTime endDate = testDate.AddDays(1);

while (testDate.Date != endDate.Date)
{
    Console.WriteLine(testDate.ToString());
    testDate = testDate.AddHours(1);
}
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - DateTimeKind Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shx7s921.aspx)

Comment: Careful of the side-effect of testDate having changed when you're finished with the loop.

Comment: @Justin does it? I'm quite curious. Because it would have to know the timezone to do that.

Comment: @dknaack I tried it and no it doesn't. And AFAIK culture isn't related to TimeZone.

Comment: "this will not work on days with 25 or 23 hours" - this is nonsense.  DateTime.AddHours doesn't take any account of daylight saving time.

Answer (score 6):

Use `for` instead:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2011,12,15);
for(int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
{
    DateTime time = date.AddHours(i);
    ...
}
```

If you *really* want to use `foreach`, you could create an extension method like this:

```
static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetHours(this DateTime date)
    {
        date = date.Date; // truncate hours
        for(int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
        {
            yield return date.AddHours(i);
        }
    }
}

...

DateTime date = new DateTime(2011,12,15);
foreach (DateTime time in date.GetHours())
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Stmated it's not modifying the original date. So at the start of each loop iteration `date` will always be the same.

Comment: Justin bought up a very good point in another answer. Not all days have 24hours!!

Comment: @Ray, that depends on what you mean by "day". Days as represented by `System.DateTime` have 24 hours, so `.AddDays(x)` and `.AddHours(x * 24)` will always have the same result (indeed, they both call the same `.Add()` method with multipliers a factor of 24 from each other). Therefore, the historical cases of time changes and cases of leap-seconds require something more sophisticated than direct use of `DateTime` anyway.

Comment: @JonHanna indeed. It requires a more sophisticated solution if that is the intent is for this to be correct for Daylight Savings.

Answer (score 1):

For those who don't like plain old for loops :) :

```
DateTime testDate = new DateTime(2011,12,15,00,00,00);
foreach (int hour in Enumerable.Range(0,24)) {
    DateTime dateWithHour = testDate.AddHours(hour);
}
```

Comment: May as well LINQify it as well ... Enumerable.Range(0,24).ForEach(hour => testDate.AddHours(hour); ... )

Comment: @nonnb `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't have a `ForEach` extension method. You'd have to `ToList()` first.

Answer (score 1):

The code below allows you to cycle through the hours of the day but also starting from a specific hour. It could be simpler if you do not need to support starting from an hour offset.

```
DateTime testDate = new DateTime(2011,12,15,13,00,00);
var hoursLeft = 24 - testDate.Hour;

for (var hour = 1; hour < hoursLeft; hour++)
{
    var nextDate = testDate.AddHours(hour);
    Console.WriteLine(nextDate);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

foreach loop works in list but here testDate.Date never gives you hour. so in substitution of it use for loop or do while or while loop.

Answer (score 1):

To get the hours in [DLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) time use this:

```
DateTime testDate = new DateTime(2017, 03, 26, 00, 00, 00, DateTimeKind.Local);
DateTime endDate = testDate.AddDays(1);

//these dates also contain time!
var start = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetDaylightChanges(testDate.Year).Start; 
var end = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetDaylightChanges(testDate.Year).End;

var hoursInDay = new List<DateTime>();

while (testDate.Date != endDate.Date)
{
    if (start == testDate)
    {
        //this day have 23 hours, and should skip this hour.
        testDate = testDate.AddHours(1);
        continue; 
    }

    hoursInDay.Add(testDate);

    if (end == testDate)
    {
        hoursInDay.Add(testDate); //this day has 25 hours. add this extra hour
    }

    testDate = testDate.AddHours(1);
}
```

I'm in Denmark, so when I run this it has only 23 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over all 24 hours of the day:

```
DateTime testDate = new DateTime(2011, 12, 15);

for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
{
    DateTime hour = testDate.Date.AddHours(i);
    // Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime tomorrow = today.AddDays(1);
for ( var i = today; i <= tomorrow; i = i.AddHours(1))
{
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score -1):

simply do this

```
DateTime testDate = new DateTime(2011, 12, 15, 10, 00, 00);
        for (int i = testDate.Hour; i < 24; i++)
        {
            //do what ever

        }
```